# HTTPS GET without DNS lookup

Tags: python, https

I need to HTTP-GET a document over TLS without having the process let the OS resolve the domain name.

The reason for this is that I know that the IP address I want to use will be correct, but fetching for https://123.123.123.123 won't give me a valid SSL certificate. Yet I know that https://example.com will have the correct certificate and be reachable at the address 123.123.123.123. The OS's resolver will very likely yield an outdated IP address in my use case.

How can I make a request to a given IP address by explicitly specifying which domain name to use for the SSL certificate?

A possible solution would be to update the `/etc/hosts` file and add an entry like `123.123.123.123 example.com`, but it requires root and I don't want to be editing that file only for this purpose.

As shown in my answer below, monkey-patching can also be an approach, though I'm not sure if it is really reliable in the long term.

Answer (score 0):

Monkey-patching [`socket.getaddrinfo`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/socket.html#socket.getaddrinfo) can be a solution when using the `resuests` package.

```
import socket
import requests

getaddrinfo_original = socket.getaddrinfo
def getaddrinfo_patched(*args, **kwargs):
  if args[0] in ['example.com']:
    return [(
      socket.AF_INET,          # family
      socket.SOCK_STREAM,      # type
      socket.IPPROTO_TCP,      # proto
      '',                      # canonname
      ('123.123.123.123', 443) # sockaddr
    )]
  return getaddrinfo_original(*args, **kwargs)
socket.getaddrinfo = getaddrinfo_patched

r = requests.get('https://example.com/')
print(r.status_code, r.content)
```

But in this case maybe `socket.gethostbyname` and other functions would need to get patched as well.